# Hide variable (e.g. 'password') from print and call of pydantic data model

Tags: python, replace, pydantic

I am using pydantic for some user/password data model. When the model is printed, I want to replace the value of password with something else (`***` for example) to prevent that the password is e.g. written into log-files or the console accidentally.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class myUserClass(BaseModel):
    User = 'foo'
    Password = 'bar'

    def __str__(self):
        return "Hidden parameters."

U = myUserClass()

print(U)
# > Hidden parameters. # Should be User='foo', Password='***' or similar

U # This will still show my password.
#> myUserClass(User='foo', Password='bar')
```

How can I access the string that is normally printed and replace only 'bar' with '***', but keeping all parameters?

How can I also do that when just calling `U`? This may not be equally important as for logging and console output usually `print` is called.

Comment: What have you tried to implement in `__str__()` so far? Where did you get stuck? Have you looked at the implementation in `BaseModel`?

Comment: I am stuck at how I can access the string that would normally be printed to replace a substring. However, the answer from @alex_noname is the perfect solution for my use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pydantic provides [`SecretStr`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#secret-types) data type. Which is replaced by *** when converted to str (e.g printed) and actual value can be obtained by `get_secret_value()` method:

```
class Foobar(BaseModel):
    password: SecretStr
    empty_password: SecretStr

# Initialize the model.
f = Foobar(password='1234', empty_password='')


# Assert str and repr are correct.
assert str(f.password) == '**********'
assert str(f.empty_password) == ''

# Assert retrieval of secret value is correct
assert f.password.get_secret_value() == '1234'
assert f.empty_password.get_secret_value() == ''
```

Comment: This is awesome. The perfect and intended solution for my use case. I obviously have overseen this feature in the docs.